# Узнать, пустой ли массив в объекте

Tags: php

Есть объект, в нем есть куча массивов. Надо узнать, пуст или нет определенный массив. Как сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения "пустоты" массива предназначена функция `empty()`.

Что можно сделать чуть лучше - завести собственную функцию с `type hinting`, которая будет работать **только для массивов,** т.к это привносит дополнительную *type safety.*

*Это можно сделать, например, так:*

```
// [a] -> Bool
function isArrayEmpty(array $a){ 
    return empty($a); 
}
```

Comment: "очень полезная функция" ^^

Comment: когда делаю if (empty($object['myarray']))

мне пишет ошибку: cannot use object of type CIBLOCKresult as array

Comment: у вас ошибка в коде значит, кстати сдесь вы проверяете на пустоту обьект а не массив каГбы

Comment: @Tchort Ну вы бы сказали сразу, что это не массив а `CDBResult` из битрикса. Тогда воспользуйтесь методом `$x->FieldsCount()` и сравните его с нулем.

Comment: @Tchort Я, правда, не уверен, не посадит ли вам такие проверки производительность, но скорее всего нет. Просто в том случае, если в битриксе выборка сделана лениво, то, например `FieldsCount()` может при вызове подгружать в себя все результаты запроса. А, например, вы всего-лишь длину хотели узнать :)

Comment: мне не нужно знать кол-во записей. Мне нужно узнать пустой в нем arResult или там что-то есть.

Comment: @Tchort В случае, если проверяемый объект - это массив, то `empty()` должен работать. В вашем случае, очевидно, это не массив, а вспомогательный объект для хранения результатов из битрикса. Если нужно провести проверку на пустоту у него, то можно просто взять поле `(количество записей)` и проверить, больше оно 0, или нет. *Мой опыт работы с битриксом, к сожалению, невелик, поэтому, не видя кода, я не могу сказать ничего точнее.*

Comment: Там будет больше 0 в любом случае, т.к там кол-во записей на страницу и прочая информация. А меня интересует именно состояние записей в массиве arResult которы внутри этого объекта.

Comment: @Tchort Ну очевидно, что типа выражения `$object['myarray']` есть `CIBLOCKresult`, что вам собственно и вывалилось в ошибке, а это не массив, а промежуточный прокси-класс в битриксе. *Наверняка, там есть способ получить ваш желаемый массив и сделать это должно быть просто; лучше, правда, спросить у кого-нибудь, кто разрабатывает на битриксе и, может быть, переформулировать вопрос в заголовке.*

Answer (score 0):

Странный вопрос... Ну например...

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
         $this->array = array();
    }
}
$obj = new A();
if(empty($obj->array)) {
    //если пустой массив обьекта...
}
```

Comment: а стандартной функции в пхп нет?

Comment: а чем вас `empty` не устраивает то?О_о<br>
Пример класса и пустого массива я привел для наглядности